# Can I change class_weight during training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I want to change my class_weight during training in Keras.

I used `fit_generator` and `Callback` method like below.

```
model.fit_generator(
                decoder_generator(x_train, y_train),
                steps_per_epoch=len(x_train),
                epochs=args.epochs,
                validation_data=decoder_generator(x_valid, y_valid),
                validation_steps=len(x_valid),
                callbacks=callback_list,
                class_weight=class_weights,
                verbose=1)
```

And

```
class Valid_checker(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, model_name, patience, val_data, x_length):
        super().__init__()
        self.best_score = 0
        self.patience = patience
        self.current_patience = 0 
        self.model_name = model_name
        self.validation_data = val_data
        self.x_length = x_length


    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        X_val, y_val = self.validation_data
        y_predict, x_predict = model.predict_generator(no_decoder_generator(X_val, y_val), steps=len(X_val))
        y_predict = np.asarray(y_predict)
        x_predict = np.asarray(x_predict)
```

`decoder_generator` and `no_decoder_generator` are just custom generator.

I want to change the class weight every time the epoch ends. Is it possible? Then how can I do?

My data is imbalanced data, and overfitting is continued for one class.

At the end of the epoch I want to increase the weight for classes with low accuracy by calculating the accuracy by class.

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a simple approach like looping over one epoch at a time ?

```
for i in range(args.epochs):
        class_weights = calculate_weights()
        model.fit_generator(
                    decoder_generator(x_train, y_train),
                    steps_per_epoch=len(x_train),
                    epochs=1,
                    validation_data=decoder_generator(x_valid, y_valid),
                    validation_steps=len(x_valid),
                    callbacks=callback_list,
                    class_weight=class_weights,
                verbose=1)
```

There is no straight forward way to use different class weights for each epoch in `fit_generator`. You can incorporate early stopping by checking the value of `model.stop_training`

#### Sample

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
from keras.callbacks import Callback

class Valid_checker(Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = model
        self.n_epoch = 0

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):   
        self.n_epoch += 1
        if self.n_epoch == 8:
            self.model.stop_training = True

def decoder_generator():
    while True:        
        for i in range(10):
            yield np.random.rand(10,5), np.random.randint(3,size=(10,3))


inputs = Input(shape=(5,))
outputs = Dense(3, activation='relu')(inputs)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

for i in range(10):    
    model.fit_generator(generator=decoder_generator(),
                    class_weight={0:1/3, 1:1/3, 2:1/3},
                    steps_per_epoch=10,                    
                    epochs=1,
                    callbacks=[Valid_checker()])
    if model.stop_training:
        break
```

Comment: I think I could try that. However, in `Valid_checker` class, I implemented custom early stopping and model saving. So I think I have to return current accuracy in `on_epoch_end` function. Do you have any other comments for me?